# Массив кнопок добавить в Layout через метод OnCreate

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно чтобы при запуске приложения вызывался метод который добавляет на экран массив кнопок, который находится в отдельном классе. пробовал по разному, получается только добавлять каждую кнопку отдельно и устанавливать для каждой текст вручную. Через for -вылетает приложение.
П.С буду очень благодарен за помощь!=)
Вот что у меня получилось:

### ## Class Button ##

```
public class ButtonFace {
 public Button[] numButtonFace;
 public void setNumButtonFace(){
 numButtonFace = new Button[10];
 String[] buttonFace = new String[10];
 buttonFace[0] = "A";
 buttonFace[1] = "B";
 buttonFace[2] = "H";
 buttonFace[3] = "F";
 buttonFace[4] = "C";
 buttonFace[5] = "E";
 buttonFace[6] = "D";
 buttonFace[7] = "S";
 buttonFace[8] = "W";
 buttonFace[9] = "Q";
 for (int i =0; i<numButtonFace.length; i++){
         numButtonFace[i].setText(buttonFace[i]);
    }
}
```

---

### ## OnCreate ##

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout top = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.top);
    Button newLayout = new Button (this);
    Button newButton = new Button(this);
    ButtonFace face = new ButtonFace();
    face.numButtonFace[0] = new Button(this);
    newButton.setText("A");
    newLayout.setText("V");
    top.addView(newLayout,params);
    top.addView(newButton,params);
    top.addView(face.numButtonFace[0]);

}
```

---

Comment: Почему не используете адаптер?

Comment: используйте ListView

Comment: Наверное потому что я не знаю как реализовать иначе, поэтому спрашиваю здесь.
Wlad, спасибо за наводку!